# Help with IF function on a formula field -

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have a feeling my parentheses are out of alignment or I need a NOT somewhere for this formula field. I have tried a few different syntaxes with no success. Error message: "Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 4".

What I want is basically:
IF Account Flags Include Operations hold, display "Operations Hold". If not, display null
OR
IF Account Flags Include Audit hold, display "Audit Hold". If not, display null

Here is the formula:

```
IF(INCLUDES(Account.Flags__c,"Operations Hold"), "Operations Hold", "",
IF(INCLUDES(Account.Flags__c,"Audit Hold"), "Audit Hold", ""
))
```

For context, `{IF(INCLUDES(Account.Flags__c,"Operations Hold"), "Operations Hold", ""}` works by itself.

Comment: Try removing `"",` after `"Operations Hold",` because `if` takes 3 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message is telling you, the `IF()` function only takes 3 parameters.

You can't just extend the `IF()` by adding another comma. Instead, you need to choose one of the 2nd or 3rd parameter, and replace it with another `IF()`. This effectively builds an if-else if-else chain.

In Apex, we do have `else if`, so that would look like

```
if(<condition 1>){
    <value if condition 1 is true>;
else if(<condition 2>){
    <value if condition 1 is false, but condition 2 is true>;
}else{
    <value if neither condition 1 or 2 are true>;
}
```

If you don't have access to `else if` (which formulas don't), then you'd need to restructure things a little

```
if(<condition 1>){
    <value if condition 1 is true>;
else{
    if(<condition 2>){
        <value if condition 1 is false, but condition 2 is true>;
    }else{
        <value if neither condition 1 or 2 are true>;
    }
}
```

That second approach is very similar to what you need to do in a formula. Keeping the indentation similar to if it were code helps illustrate that (and is in general a good way to keep formulas organized so that they're easy to read and spot mistakes in)

```
IF(
    <condition 1>,
    <value if condition 1 is true>,
    IF(
        <condition 2>,
        <value if condition 1 is false, but condition 2 is true>,
        <value if neither condition 1 or 2 are true>
    )
)
```

Applied to your specific scenario

```
IF(
    INCLUDES(Account.Flags__c,"Operations Hold"), 
    "Operations Hold",
    IF(
        INCLUDES(Account.Flags__c,"Audit Hold"), 
        "Audit Hold", 
        ""
    )
)
```

Comment: N.B. I tend to prefer `NULL` over `""`

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation on how the function should work. Unfortunately I am not achieving the desired results, as the formula field is not populated with "Audit Hold" when the Flags field on the Account has Audit Flag selected. Operations Hold does display if that is true on the Account however. Does it matter if Account.Flags__c is a multi picklist? Thinking maybe this is a limitation of Formula fields in that regard?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using this formula :

{IF(INCLUDES(Account.Flags__c,"Operations Hold"), "Operations Hold", (IF(INCLUDES(Account.Flags__c,"Audit Hold"), "Audit Hold", ""))}

Comment: I appreciate the quick response! No Syntax error, but the field does not populate with "Audit Hold" when the Flags field on the Account has Audit Flag selected. Operations Hold does display if that is true on the Account however.

Comment: The values ("Operations Hold", "Audit Hold") written in formula must match the actual values. Can you check on that record if the Audit Hold as 'A' and 'H' as caps ???

Comment: May be some spelling or Case sensitivity issue. Thanks.

Comment: Spelling and capitalization matches between the formula and the actual picklist values. Does it perhaps matter if Account.Flags__c is a multi picklist?